# How to create own NuGet V3 API

Tags: nuget-server

Now we have our own nuget feed using NuGet.Server v2.10.1 , we are facing issue in installing UWP NuGet packages, the packages listed in Visual studio but cant able to install getting not found error, after referred in some sites, they told to use nuget api v3 tokens for vs2015 packages, how can i create Nuget API v2 and V3 API and provide separate nuget links.. as like in the myget nuget feed